# Find out from which control a popup menu is triggered

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsmenu

I have a series of NSButtons on a window, whose `menu` property is connected to a common NSMenu in the storyboard. In the action method triggered by that menu's item(s), I would like to find out which button was right-clicked to open the menu. How can I do that?

The event (`[[NSApplication sharedApplication] currentEvent]`) does not seem to contain that information.

Comment: Before an `NSView` presents a menu, it calls `willOpenMenu:withEvent:`. Override that on your buttons and remember which button opened the menu. Alternatively, you could attach a delegate to the menu and capture the same information in `menuWillOpen:`, but I'm not sure which would be more work.

Comment: Thanks. The delegate aproach does not solve the problem, as I still have no information from which button the menu was triggered. Subclassing the buttons appears to work, however I found it simpler to create a separate menu for each button in code and give them separate tags.

Comment: The delegate would have to get the current event and the then use the window's `contentView` to perform a `hitTest:`  to discover the control that the contextual menu click occurred on. That's why I said it would be a lot of work. But separate menus works too!